# Unexpected error during automatic discovery process for cloud provider during apm agent initialization

Tags: elasticsearch

Unexpected error during automatic discovery process for cloud provider during apm agent initialization. Any ideas on why this happens?

```
2021-04-28 16:05:43,132 [elastic-apm-metadata] WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.CloudMetadataProvider - Unexpected error during automatic discovery process for cloud provider
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204) ~[?:?]
        at co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.CloudMetadataProvider.tryAllCloudProviders(CloudMetadataProvider.java:165) [?:?]
        at co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.CloudMetadataProvider.fetchAndParseCloudProviderInfo(CloudMetadataProvider.java:107) [?:?]
        at co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.MetaData$1.call(MetaData.java:125) [?:?]
        at co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.MetaData$1.call(MetaData.java:121) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
2021-04-28 16:05:43,414 [elastic-apm-server-healthcheck] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.ApmServerHealthChecker - Elastic APM server is available: {  "build_date": "2021-03-18T05:15:57Z",  "build_sha": "ef735c0cc1e5aa0d4fe4a363804390776e7775fe",  "version": "7.12.0"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the same message, by removing the `-Delastic.apm.transaction_max_spans` option the error disappears!

Comment: @buddemat, We do not even have this option any where in our spring cloud gateway code and we are still seeing this error, is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to assign the option `cloud_provider` as `NONE`.

That will escape the [fetchAndParseCloudProviderInfo](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/blob/v1.30.1/apm-agent-core/src/main/java/co/elastic/apm/agent/impl/metadata/CloudMetadataProvider.java#L97-L136).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/master/config-core.html#config-cloud-provider